# Open link in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, target

I have a Webpage with an iframe in it.

I want the links, when clicked, to open them in the frame.

I tried `<a href="" target="nameofframe">link1</a>` but it didnt' work?

How can web links be displayed in a frame?

Comment: Your way should work. Give us more, actual code.

Comment: shared my solution here https://alfilatov.com/posts/how-to-open-links-from-iframe/

Answer (score 63):

Assuming the iFrame has a name attribute of "myIframe":

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="myIframe">Link Text</a>
```

You can also accomplish this with the use of Javascript. The iFrame has a src attribute which specifies the location it shows. As such, it's a simple matter of binding the click of a link to changing that src attribute.

Comment: Here's a simple demo of this: http://jsfiddle.net/HnXFj/2/

Comment: Please note its "name" attribute of iframe, not ID.   <iframe name="myIframe" id="iframe1"></iframe>

Answer (score 46):

Try this:

```
<iframe name="iframe1" src="target.html"></iframe>

<a href="link.html" target="iframe1">link</a>
```

The "target" attribute should open in the iframe.

Answer (score 9):

Use attribute name.

Here you can find the solution ("Use iframe as a Target for a Link"):
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_iframe.asp

Answer (score 5):

```
<a href="YOUR_URL" target="_YOUR_IFRAME_NAME">LINK NAME</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the target of the link matches the name of the iframe, the link will open in the iframe.
Try this:

```
<iframe src="http://stackoverflow.com/" name="iframe_a">
<p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<a href="http://www.cnn.com" target="iframe_a">www.cnn.com</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem in a project this morning. Make sure you specify the base tag in the head section.

It should be like this:

```
<head>
<base target="name_of_iframe">
</head>
```

That way when you click a link on the page it will open up inside of the iframe by default.

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's an alternate way! You can use a button instead of hyperlink. Hence, when the button is clicked the web page specified in "name_of_webpage" is opened in the target frame named "name_of_iframe". It works for me!

```
<form method="post" action="name_of_webpage" target="name_of_iframe">
<input type="submit" value="any_name_you_want" />
</form>
<iframe name="name_of_iframe"></iframe>
```