# Facebook and Twitter share via iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, twitter

I want to share `referral url` from my site via Twitter/Facebook share buttons. I have customized share buttons.
I am able to share referral url on these two sites but because `target=_blank`, facebook's Share Link and Twitter's Tweet page appears on a new tab. 
I want then in an `iFrame` so that user won't leave my website while sharing referral links.

**Facebook Share Code**

```
<a title="send to Facebook"
                 href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT"
                 target="_blank">
                 <span>
```

**Twitter Share Code**

```
<a href="#" id="shareWithTwitter" onclick="shareWithTwitter()">
                  <img class="social-share"  src="<?php echo site_url('img/twitter.png'); ?>"/>
                </a>
function shareWithTwitter()
  {
    var url = 'https://twitter.com/home?status=Join Fashion on '+$('#referal-URL').val();
    $('#shareWithTwitter').attr('href',url);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is adding a name attribute to the iframe and target your link to it.

```
<iframe name="iframeName" style="iframe style"></iframe>
<a href="YOUR LINK" target="iframeName">link </a>
```

[open link in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe)