# How to open link in popup box?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to open  this link as a popup box:

```
  <a href="/upload/" onclick="window.open(this.href, 'windowName', 'width=500, height=350, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable'); return false;">Upload pic</a>
```

Currently, it opens in a window, but what I want is a bare popub box instead. How to do so using js or jQuery?

**Update**: 
The link is inside a form group and using iframe, as suggested by many [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe), causes the form to submit (not sure why though). So I look for a non-iframe solution.

Comment: Look at jQuery UI https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 2):

**Build your own popup box with an `iframe` element;**

`onclick` you can change the `src` of the iframe to the one you want

---

```js
document.getElementById('modalBtn').onclick = displayPopup;

function displayPopup() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("popup");
  var frame = document.getElementById('popupFrame');
  frame.src = "https://www.bing.com";
  popup.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#popup {
  width: 320px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px black;
  display: none;
}
#popup iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
  <iframe id="popupFrame" src=""></iframe>
</div>

<button id="modalBtn">Display Popup</button>
```

Comment: @randi Pair this with a bootstrap modal or similar and you'd be good to go

Comment: @DelightedD0D how to add onclick event to this?

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides Unfortunately, in my implementation the iframe just flickers onclick and disappears immediately. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Whoops.. misread your question

**Re-answer:**

Use jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#testButton").click(function() {$('#overlayContainer').show();});
});
```

[Jsfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RNe4T/6/)

Comment: Isn't this the same result as the OPs code? You've just made it into a separate function

Comment: and this does not open the desired link.

Comment: How to add the destination link `/upload/` to this snippet?

Comment: Use fancybox.net 'iFrame method'