# Is it possible to contain a popup to an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, html

This is the code being used for a popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-cfasync="false">    
var _pop = _pop || [];    
_pop.push(['siteId', 1444526]);    
_pop.push(['minBid', 0]);    
_pop.push(['popundersPerIP', 0]);    
_pop.push(['delayBetween', 0]);    
_pop.push(['default', false]);    
_pop.push(['defaultPerDay', 0]);    
_pop.push(['topmostLayer', false]);    
(function() {    
var pa = document.createElement('script'); pa.type = 'text/javascript'; pa.async = true;    
var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];    
pa.src = '//c1.popads.net/pop.js';    
pa.onerror = function() {    
var sa = document.createElement('script'); sa.type = 'text/javascript'; sa.async = true;    
sa.src = '//c2.popads.net/pop.js';    
s.parentNode.insertBefore(sa, s);    
};    
s.parentNode.insertBefore(pa, s);    
})();    
</script>
```

Is there any way to make it so that the popup is contain to an iframe on my page?  Basically I'm trying to prevent the popup from occurring and basically send it into an iFrame - so visitors see it there instead of in a new tab/window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29860599/how-to-open-link-in-popup-box

Comment: Is the iframe source on the same domain as the containing window? If not the answer is probably no due to same-origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible due to X-Frame-Options header...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Whilst this link may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also note that [answers that are barely more than a link are subject to deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer).

Comment: This single statement above the link really answers the question. The problem is in **presence** of that header, regardless of its value - because any will cause problems when trying to embed such page into `iframe`. Apart from that, what's the point in supporting fraudulent people?