# Link loads in new page, not iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

OK, I've not used iframes for a long time but this problem is so basic I must be missing something really obvious.

I have a page (Page A) containing a link (to Page B in the same domain/folder as the parent) that I want to open in an iframe in Page A.

pageA.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page A</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="/pageB.html" target="tgt">Load ...</a><br>
<iframe id="tgt"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

pageB.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page B</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This is a test. Should load in iframe.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

When the link is clicked pageB opens in a new page (as if the target id isn't present), not in the iframe in pageA.

What am I doing wrong?

=========================================================

OK, sorted that but now I need to do this using php generated JavaScript.  Here is a very minimal example:

pageA.php (parent page):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page A</title>

<?php
$srcPage = "/pageB.html";
echo "
<script>
function loadIframe() {
    window.alert('Clicked, loading $srcPage');
    document.getElementById('tgt').attr('src', '$srcPage');
}
</script>
";?>

</head>

<body>
<p id="load" onclick="loadIframe()">[Click me to load] ...</p>
<iframe id="tgt" name="tgt"></iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

pageB.html (page to load - same as before):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Page B</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is a test. Should load in iframe.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The script executes (alert is displayed) but the page doesn't load.

Thanks

Nigel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the attribute `name="tgt"` to your iframe.

[open link in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe)

For your second question, you mixed jquery with plain javascript.
This is how you change the `src` of an `iframe` using plain javascript:

`document.getElementById('iframeid').src = '$srcPage'`