# jquery - Iframe content text click event not working

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am using menu type and that respective content load in iframe with same domain url.
When click the  div(using class name)  inside the iframe content i need to reload the url.

I tried the following code.

Html Code:

```
<ul>
<li href="http://mywebsite/contact">contact</li>
<li href="http://mywebsite/faq">faq</li>
<li href="http://mywebsite/abcd">abcd</li>
</ul>

<iframe  class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://mywebsite/contact" id="right_content_iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="width:100%;border:0px;min-height:500px;" ></iframe>
```

Js Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('ul.li').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if ($(this).attr('href')) {
                console.log($(this).attr('href'));
                $('#right_content_iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
                e.preventDefault();
            }
        });

        var iframe = $('#right_content_iframe').contents();
        console.log(iframe);
        iframe.find(".page_refresh").click(function() {
            location.reload();
        });

    });
```

The default contact page will load in iframe.
When i click the faq link the iframe url load http://mywebsite/faq. On that time when i click the div (.page_refres) in faq page I need to reload the url.

Faq Page:

```
<div>Same text</div>
<div class="page_refresh" > Page Refresh</div>
```

Comment: But you don't need javascript for the menu if you're using an iframe... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe

Answer (score 0):

Hi have my own project which i use iframe quite a bit... revsisted the code as i know what you want is in there somewhere... to get my project working again i first had to do....
check browser console for:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode?answertab=active#tab-top
```

I had to run...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files
```

I also had to restart all my chrome instances.

### I will now proceed to find the line that you need.

cant remember what i was all doing... and my was way more complicated.
but it seems like I just replaced the whole iframe with the new url.

```
window.parent.$('#sumdiv').html('<iframe  id="myIframe" style="border: 0px; " src="' + url + '" width="100%" height="100%" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>');
```

This should help

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this is incorrect:

```
 <li href=".....
```

If you don't want to write an `<a>` tag you can use datasets:

```
 <li data-href="......
```

Is more correct.
In the second point, your selector is wrong:

```
 $('ul.li').click(function(e) {
```

This means the ul with class li. You need to select li childs in a ul with this:

```
 $('ul li').click(function(e) {
 // --^
```

Note that dot disappears.

Complete code:

```
 <ul>
   <li data-href="http://mywebsite/contact">contact</li>
   <li data-href="http://mywebsite/faq">faq</li>
   <li data-href="http://mywebsite/abcd">abcd</li>
 </ul>

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul li').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var href = $(this).attr('data-href');
        if (href) {
            $('#right_content_iframe').attr('src', href);
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    var iframe = $('#right_content_iframe').contents();
    iframe.find(".page_refresh").click(function() {
        location.reload();
    });

});
```