# click a link in 1 frame and browse the link in 2nd frame

Tags: html

A link should be given in one frame. When it will be clicked , then it will open in another frame.when I gave a html page link,the code works .But if I put a web page like: https://www.facebook.com/,then the code is not working.

why is it so?
the code is :

frames_example_1 page :

```
  <frameset cols="200,*" frameborder="0" border="0" framespacing="0">
<frame name="menu" src="menu_1.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
<frame name="content" src="content.html" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" scrolling="auto" noresize>
```

Menu_1.html :

```
menu_1.html  : <p><a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="content">Facebook</a></p>
```

Comment: Its because of the [Same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) which is in place for security purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [open link in iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe)

Comment: then what is the solution ? @AhsN

Comment: @learner Simply you can't :)

Comment: I got something.the above code works for only http websites but it is not working for https website. can suggest any solution? @AhsN