# I want when i click on <a href="whatever.aspx"></a> show the page inside the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, database

**That is my code:**

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlGallery" runat="server" RepeatLayout="Flow" Width="100%" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333">

  <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
  <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
  <ItemStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />

  <ItemTemplate>                    
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="Album.aspx?GalleryId=<%#Eval("GalleryId") %>">
            <%# Eval("GalleryName") %>
              </a>
            </td>
        <td>
          <%# Eval("GalleryDescription") %>
            </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </ItemTemplate>
  <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
</asp:DataList>
```

I want when i click on the a-tag the page dispaly in the iframe-tage .
I have an idea that use (onclick) with a-tag but i do not know how can i do it.
If there another way please tell me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the target attribute of the a-tag and give the name of the iframe as the target. This will load the page in the href to the iframe when you click on the link.
eg.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe  name="nn" src=""></iframe>
<a href="test.html" target="nn">link</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

" target="iframe1">

That is the answer thanks @freedomn-m