# How to load a specific section for a website embedded in iframe from an external href?

Tags: html, iframe

I've got a Wordpress website hosted with a page that contains an  and within this iframe I have a few html pages like overview.html, diagram.html etc. In these html pages there are sections containing an ID that I can use to link to using #overview-chapter-1 (for example). However I do not want to do this linking from the containing parent, but from a different website hosted somewhere else.

**What would I like to achieve?**

I would like to open a specific section of the website that is embedded in the iframe from a **different** website than the parent containing this [iframe](/questions/tagged/iframe).

1. So for example I have the following iframe which is hosted on
2. example.com. The overview.html contains a div named **link-to-me**.
3. How am I able to link to the overview.html#link-to-me from an  that is not on the same website?

Please read this before answering the question:

> This is not what I am looking for because this only applies to a link inside the same page. [open link in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/740816/open-link-in-iframe)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Site A has a page with an iframe (this is parent). The iframe is to another page within site A (this is child). You want site B with a link to site A's child page? `http://host.com/path/to/overview.html#link-to-me`

Comment: @zer00ne Site A has a page with an iframe (this is the parent indeed).  The iframe is to another page within site A (this is the child indeed). I want site C (an external site which is hosted somewhere else) to open a link inside website (B) in the iframe from site A.